# Как сделать, чтобы JS-код применялся ко всем прописанным классам?

Tags: javascript

Есть код, его суть в том, что он копирует текстовое значение указанного класса и вставляет его в отмеченный в скрипте второй класс. Но почему-то код применяется только к первому классу. В чем может быть проблема?

```js
window.onload = function () {
 let title = document.getElementsByClassName('product-title-main');
 let paste = document.getElementsByClassName('insert-here');
 paste[0].innerHTML = title[0].innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="product-title-main">"Рахат-Лукум"</h1>
<h2>Купить <span class="insert-here"></span></h2>
<h2>Отзыв о <span class="insert-here"></span></h2>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Я бы вместо `document.getElementsByClassName('product-title-main')` использовал`document.querySelectorAll('.product-title-main')`. Ну и для второго класса - тоже. В любом случае, элементы надо перебирать в цикле.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
window.onload = function () {
 let title = document.getElementsByClassName('product-title-main');
 let paste = document.getElementsByClassName('insert-here');
 [...paste].forEach(el => el.innerHTML = title[0].innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<h1 class="product-title-main">"Рахат-Лукум"</h1>
<h2>Купить <span class="insert-here"></span></h2>
<h2>Отзыв о <span class="insert-here"></span></h2>
```